# r shiny server is running, but the app is not working

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

We have built shiny-server on linux ubuntu, I check the status and the shiny-server.conf and both seems to be okay but not able to run the app, please see as below:
1. The shiny-server status:

```
  root@ubuntu:~# sudo status shiny-server
  shiny-server start/running, process 43150
```

2. The server.conf

   ```
   # Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
   run_as shiny;

   # Define a server that listens on port 3838
   server {
     listen 3838;

     # Define a location at the base URL
     location / {

       # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
       site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

       # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
       log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

       # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
       # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
       directory_index on;
     }
   }
   ```

However, when I put the `server.R` and `UI.R` files under `srv/shiny-server` and then run the URL, it is in vain and shows "Not found".

```
 http://<my_server>:3838/<app_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code shows an allappfolders created, under which you can create various apps like app1, app2..etc.

Below will display all apps under

```
http://<my_server>:3838/allappfolders
```

Below app1 will load the ui.R and server.R

```
http://<my_server>:3838/allappfolders/app1
```

Full conf. code below:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

    location /users {
      run_as :HOME_USER:;
      user_dirs;
    }

    # Define a location at the base URL
    location /allappfolders {
        run_as shiny;

        # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
        site_dir /opt/shiny-server/allappfolders;

        # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
        log_dir /var/log/shiny-server/allappfolders;

        # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
        # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
        directory_index on;
    };

    # Define a location at the base URL
    location /app1 {

        # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
        app_dir /opt/shiny-server/allappfolders/app1;

        # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
        log_dir /var/log/shiny-server/app1;

        # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
        # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
        directory_index off;
    };

    # Define a location at the base URL
    location /app2 {

        # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
        app_dir /opt/shiny-server/allappfolders/app2;

        # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
        log_dir /var/log/shiny-server/app2;

        # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
        # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
        directory_index off;
    };

}
```

Comment: /srv folder has symbolic links to /opt folder. So it is preferred to ftp all files to /opt/shiny-server/<your_directory>

Comment: I put the files to  **/opt/shiny-server/<your_directory>** but it still not works; actually it worked fine before, and the ui.R and server.R are under **/srv/shiny-server** folder. So I assume it might be other issue caused the failure.

Comment: The sample-apps that come with shiny-server installation have Linux symbolic link from /srv/shiny-server folder to /opt/shiny-server/sample-apps.

Comment: I recommend to ignore the /srv folder and create everything under /opt as in configuration code above. Do not place app files under the main directory (allappsfolder in my conf). Using FTP software connect and create another app1 and place your .R files. If you do not want app1 subfolder then turn dir_index off in allappsfolder and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

3838 port IPTABLES issue: I installed SHiny Server on a fresh LINUX CENTOS system.
Everything was fine but the sample app was not loading.
Luckily my colleague was a LINUX NERD and quickly checked the port IPTABLE entries.
He set it to OFF and EUREKA! my sample app was up and running.
Just had to install rmarkdown package as system was connected to internet.